# I need to aggregate and transpose one column to rows in Pyspark (long to wide format)

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I need to "explode" one column to multiple columns - similar to pivot but I need new column names.

Give this spark dataframe:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
[(1, 6, 200),
  (1, 6, 300),
  (1, 6, 400),
  (1, 7, 1000),
  (1, 6, 5000)],  
"id int, term int, amount int")

df.show()

+---+----+------+
| id|term|amount|
+---+----+------+
|  1|   6|   200|
|  1|   6|   300|
|  1|   6|   400|
|  1|   7|  1000|
|  1|   7|  5000|
+---+----+------+
```

How can break "amount" into new columns? Some cells will be empty, which is ok.

[image]

Comment: Do you know the max number of `amount` (rows) per `term`?   and how do you decide 1000 to go `amt-1`?  `amt-1`... `amt-x` is in the order of lowest amount to the highest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group by `id / term` columns with collecting `amount` values into list, select resulting columns basing on the `max` size of `amt` (derived from `amount`) *array* column:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

new_df = (df.groupBy(['id', 'term'])
          .agg(F.collect_list(F.col("amount")).alias("amt")))
# get the max size of an array in `amt` column
max_arr_size = new_df.select(F.max(F.size('amt'))).first()[0]

new_df.select('id', 'term', *[F.col('amt')[i].alias(f'amt_{i+1}')
                              for i in range(max_arr_size)]).show()
```

---

```
+---+----+-----+-----+-----+
| id|term|amt_1|amt_2|amt_3|
+---+----+-----+-----+-----+
|  1|   6|  200|  300|  400|
|  1|   7| 1000| 5000| null|
+---+----+-----+-----+-----+
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

maybe you can try this

```py
df.groupBy("id", "term").pivot("amount").agg(first("amount")).show()
```

you will get

```
+---+----+----+----+----+----+----+
| id|term| 200| 300| 400|1000|5000|
+---+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|  1|   7|null|null|null|1000|null|
|  1|   6| 200| 300| 400|null|5000|
+---+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

and you can rename the column use the `withColumnRenamed` function

I have no better way to change the column name. - -